# Setw and setfill as it's used in a SHA256 hash function

Tags: c++, hash, openssl, std

While learning some basics with OpenSSL I came across code to [create an SHA256 hash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10632725/3124292):

```
using namespace std;

    #include <openssl/sha.h>
    string sha256(const string str)
    {
        unsigned char hash[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
        SHA256_CTX sha256;
        SHA256_Init(&sha256);
        SHA256_Update(&sha256, str.c_str(), str.size());
        SHA256_Final(hash, &sha256);
        stringstream ss;
        for(int i = 0; i < SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
        {
            ss << hex << setw(2) << setfill('0') << (int)hash[i];
        }
        return ss.str();
    }
```

**Can someone please explain what** `ss << hex << setw(2) << setfill('0') << (int)hash[i];` does in **this specific example** as simply as possible, while still explaining it efficiently?

As I can't seem to make sense of these answers, they aren't helping with understanding my specific snippet:

- [Using setw and setfill on string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37632169)
- [How to use setw and setfill together in C++ to pad with blanks AND chars](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18879039)
- [C++ output formatting using setw and setfill](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34730587)

Comment: Do you know what each of the [manipulators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip) do on their own? Have you tried experimenting with them while printing to `std::cout`?

Comment: Then you should probably [find a good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) as it should explain these *manipulators* and what they do. You could also do the output to `cout` instead of `ss` and see what you get. And most importantly, experiment! :)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  I do not, I hardly know anything on std:: anything as I am just switching to c++ from C, and I'm having a hard time learning everything at once and making sense of docs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++ there are many different *streams*. You probably know about `cout` to write output to the console, and `cin` to read input. [`stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) is a class whose object write to and read from [`string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) objects. Writing to a string stream (like the variable `ss`) is just like writing to `cout`, but writes to a string instead of the console.

You say you have programmed C? Then you should know about hexadecimal notation, right? That is what [the `hex` manipulator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex) tells the stream to use. This is similar to the `printf` format specifier `"%x"`.

[The `setw` manipulator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) sets the field width of the next output.

[The `setfill` manipulator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfill) sets the *fill* character of the output.

Finally the casting of `hash[i]` to `int` is because `hash[i]` is a `char` and output to a stream will write it as a character and not a small integer.

In short,

```
ss << hex << setw(2) << setfill('0') << (int)hash[i];
```

is equivalent to the C code

```
sprintf(temporaryBuffer, "%02x", hash[i]);
strcat(ss, temporaryBuffer);
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Made sense of the whole matter very well!